# what happens if i set input size to 32,32 mnist

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, keras, mnist, vgg-net

I want to train MNIST on VGG16.

MNIST image size is 28*28 and I set the input size to 32*32 in keras VGG16. When I train I get good metrics, but I´m not sure what really happens. Is keras filling in with empty space or is the image being expanded linearly, like in a zoom function? Anyone understands how I can get a test accuracy of +95% after 60 epochs?

Here I define target size:

```
    target_size = (32, 32)
```

This is where I define my flow_from_dataframe generator:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("cv1_train.csv", quoting=3)

train_df_generator = train_image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    directory="../../../MNIST",
    target_size=target_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
)
```

Here I define my input size:

```
model_base = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, 
             input_shape=(32, 32, 3), classes=10)
```

Comment: Please add code, its not clear what you are doing, because if you set input shape to 32x2, you would get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images would be simply resized to the specified `target_size`. This has been clearly stated in the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe):

> **target_size:** tuple of integers `(height, width)`, default: `(256, 256)`. The dimensions to which all images found will be resized.

You can also inspect the source code and find the relevant part in the [`load_img`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6ff9af6971f97f69c39d090be15c2f7d93aa4d6d/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L121) function. Also the default interpolation method used to resize the images is `nearest`. You can find more information about various interpolation methods [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/interpolation-methods.html) (MATLAB) or [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) (PIL).

Comment: Im writing a thesis and want to know more about "nearset", since it seem to be the interpolation method. Do you know where I would find more information about it? Ive searched some but dont seem to find anything...

Comment: @iKnowItAll Well, you can search with a query like "nearest interpolation image processing". For example, I could find [this](https://www.imageeprocessing.com/2017/11/nearest-neighbor-interpolation.html) or [this](https://www.giassa.net/?page_id=207). Although the MATLAB doc I linked to in my answer also provides a brief explanation. Further, probably you can find relevant information in a reference image processing book.

Comment: Thank you so much. YOu wrote "nearset" not "nearest", why I did not find anything. Ill check the litterature!

Comment: @iKnowItAll Oh, sorry! Fixed the typo. Thanks for mentioning it.